# How can I check if my 1995 Lancer CC GI has OBD-II

Tags: tools, obd-ii

As my title say I want to know if my current car that I just purchased has an ODB-II port.

I have looked under the steering wheel and I can see what I think to be a OBD-II connector, but am unsure. Does any one know where I can find out if it is or not and what protocols it uses. I know OBD-II was compulsory after 1996.

I would like to purchase some parts to work into an Arduino project, just don't want to waste money if there not needed. Really after speed and RPM info fuel would be nice, but its an old carby so I'm pretty sure there is no electric fuel pump.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the ALDL connector if you have this on it's OBD II

[image]

If you have something differant like the one below, it' not OBD II

[image]

Comment: Well it looks like this, I have just purchased a cheap model off ebay. So hopefully it will work and I can have a look, if not I will resell it

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about where you are, but around here, one can borrow an OBD-II reader from most auto parts stores.  You could borrow one and give it a try to see if it can connect...

May not have full functionality even if it does connect though.  My '95 Eclipse has the OBD-II connector and ECU, but it's not 100% compliant (also, I've been told that there were recalls for certain OBD-II bugs for 2nd generation DSMs, but that the recall is only valid for '96-'99 despite the bugs being in the '95 ECU as well).  OBD-II didn't become mandatory here until '96, appears that '95 model year cars had a beta/field-test version of it...

Comment: Don't know any mechanics so just gonna pick one up

Answer (score 0):

There's a website/project called the OBD Clearinghouse run by Weber State University - it's the authoritative database of vehicle OBD compatibility information (at least for vehicles sold in the US).

http://www.obdclearinghouse.com/index.php?body=oemdb - the OEM DB has a database of vehicles by manufacturer, model and year that lists the location of the connector, the pinout, and the communication protocol.

The Lancer is only listed from 2002 up, though this seems like it may be an error, as all cars sold in the US were required to have OBD in 1996 (as you said) and I'm pretty sure most manufacturers made it global at that point, at least for anything close to a US model, since most of the work would be done.

I wish I could be of more help, but aside from just borrowing a scantool like Brian suggested, I think your best bet might be finding an Australian mitsubishi forum and asking there... or maybe ask your local mechanic?